# My Recyclerview is inside in NestedScrollview it is working but scrolling is not working smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I tried almost everything but did not get a perfect smooth scrolling. please help Me. Thanks in Advance

**this is my layout**

```
<com.agribazaar.android.views.StickyScrollView style="@style/MatchParent">
       <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_auctions"
                style="@style/MatchWidth"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_upcoming"
                    style="@style/MatchWidth"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:padding="@dimen/m4dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </com.agribazaar.android.views.StickyScrollView>
```

Comment: can please share your code?

Comment: is there any specific reason for nested scrolling ?

Comment: yes because i also want to use different views with recyclerview

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion and in which Os version you are testing?

Comment: @Sachin Varma my MinSdkVersion is 15 and  I am testing in 25

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: try to hardcode linearlayout's height like { android:layout_height="200dp" }.. if it works now then you have to set height dynamically